# MySQL - How can I group music together when the names are similar?

Tags: mysql, grouping, similarity

I would like to be able to return a single line when the name of some musics are the same or similar, as for example this case:
[music with similar names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmw23.png)

You can see that the names are the same with an extension like " - JP Ver." or something like that, I would like to be able to group them in one row with the first column incrementing the whole.

My current request to return these lines is as follows:

```
select count(id) number, name, sec_to_time(floor(sum(duration) / 1000)) time
from track
where user_id = 'value'
group by name, duration
order by number desc, time desc;
```

[I would like to get a result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPJ3W.png)

Thank you for reading and responding! I wish you all a good day!

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the end result?

Comment: @Hexman I would like to get a result like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPJ3W.png
Thank you for your answer

Comment: You are using sum(duration) and taking duration in Group By !  I think here is the logical error lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) no,
       TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '-', 1)) namee
FROM track
GROUP BY namee
```

Example: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xt3bfev6

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT
Here is a proof of concept script. You can add your other columns. I have grouped by the first 4 letters. You will probably want to use more.

```
CREATE TABLE track (
        idd INT,
        nam CHAR(50),
        tim INT
        );
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Abba 1',5);
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Abba 2',6);
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Beta 1',12);
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Beta 4',8);

SELECT
        LEFT(nam,4) AS 'Group',
        COUNT(idd) AS 'Number',
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT idd ORDER BY idd ASC SEPARATOR ' & ') AS IDs,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nam ORDER BY nam ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'track names',
        SUM(tim) AS 'total time'
FROM track
GROUP BY LEFT(nam,4);
DROP TABLE track;
```

Output

```
Group   Number  IDs     track names     total time
Abba    2       1 & 2   Abba 1, Abba 2  11
Beta    2       3 & 4   Beta 1, Beta 4  20
```

Comment: it can be practical however I don't know the length of the title of the musics, I take note!

Comment: @Miyonu Please accept my answer if it helps. Thank you